# newbie print struct C programming question

Tags: c

I am new in C programming, and trying to create simple code below for printing a struct member using other function.

I do not understand this, as in the function funct_to_print_value, I already declare the struct variable "car", and I believe what I need is just to print is using (dot) notation to access it. Appereantly not, as I got the error above. Does anyone can share their knowledge, how I can print the value of buyer, and what mistake I had done above?

Thank you ..

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>


typedef struct slot_car {
    int buyer;
} slot_car;



int main() {



    slot_car car;
    memset(&car, 0, sizeof(car));
    car.buyer = 1;

    printf("value of car is .. %d\n", car.buyer);

    funct_to_print_value();
    printf("end of function..\n");
    return 0;
}

int funct_to_print_value()
{
    printf("you are in printlist function..\n");
    slot_car car;
    printf("value of car inside is %d\n", car.buyer);

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: The only thing I see to warn about in "function_to_print" is that variable `car` is not initialized.

Comment: That is a warning, not an error. Does the program work?

Comment: Your program [compiles and runs](http://ideone.com/wUfaJ), Are you sure you have pasted the correct code?

Comment: In funct_to_print_value car is not initialized (compare what you are doing in main, with the memset and setting car.buyer to 1).

Comment: it work, but it returns me "value of car inside is 16843009". whilst I expect to get a "1"..

Comment: heike you are forgetting initializing. Also, please be more accurate when reporting the output/errors/warnings received, otherwise it becomes an exercise in guessing...

Comment: This code does not produce that warning. Is this the real code, and what compiler do you use?

Comment: @heike: You don't get 1, because the `car` used inside the function `funct_to_print` has not been initialized. It is different from the variable `car` used in `main`.

Comment: I have an off topic question just from my own curiosity, which is why I'm adding as a comment. Why are you learning C at this time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you declared car inside each function separately, they are separate (local) variables. You probably want to pass it from main to funct_to_print_value as a parameter instead. The warning is strange, but it is possible that the compiler detected the uninitiated value and gave this message because it is first used in printf.

Answer (score 0):

This looks fine to me. It would be helpful to have more information. All I did was extract your example into a temp.c file and compile it using gcc -c temp.c. There were no errors.

On which OS is this?

Which build environment/compiler is this?

How are you building this? (commands used in the build environment)

I'm using gcc 4.4.3 on Ubuntu Linux 10.04.

### Edit 1:

What happens if you cast car.buyer to an int?

> printf("value of car is .. %d\n", (int ) car.buyer);

### Edit 2:

How about this to print your 1?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>


typedef struct slot_car {
    int buyer;
} slot_car;



int main() {



    slot_car car;
    memset(&car, 0, sizeof(car));
    car.buyer = 1;

    printf("value of car is .. %d\n", car.buyer);

    {
       int temp_ret;
       temp_ret = funct_to_print_value();
       printf("end of function..%d\n",temp_ret);
    }
    return 0;
}

int funct_to_print_value()
{
    printf("you are in printlist function..\n");
    slot_car car;
    printf("value of car inside is %d\n", car.buyer);

    return 1;
}

value of car is .. 1
you are in printlist function..
value of car inside is 134514096
end of function..1
cnorton@steamboy:~/scratch$
```

Comment: it returns me with this : "value of car is .. 16843009".

Comment: It shouldn't have to be cast. I am curious to see how heike's compiler will react to this.

Comment: Without the warning? "it returns me with this : "value of car is .. 16843009". – heike 2 mins ago"

Comment: yes, without the warning. sorry, I mistakenly execute the wrong file (edit the question).. :(